# git squash older commits (not last one)

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a very messy git history. I want to squash a bunch of older commits (not including the last one).

I know how to squash my last `n` commits. But this is different. Here I have commits consecutively `n1` to `n2` which I want to squash into one, while after `n2` I have a history of commits that I want to preserve up to the last one.

So, if my current history looks like this:

```
---- n1 --- n2 -------- m
```

I want to squash `n1` to `n2` so it ends up looking like this:

```
---- n1n2 -------- m
```

where `n1n2` is a single commit containing the squashed contents from `n1` to `n2`.

How should I do this? What are the consequences on the history from `n2` to `m`?

That is, **will the hash of every commit from `n2` to `m` change as a consequence of what I want to do?**

Comment: 1. Interactive rebase, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History. 2. Every commit from n1, which is also rewritten, yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just to confirm, ALL commits from`n2+1` to `m` will also get new hashes?

Comment: Yes, because they all have new parent commits now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So commits `1,...,n1` will preserve their hash, even if some of them are included in the interactive rebase but with `pick`.

Comment: Not necessarily, a few things go into the commit including a timestamp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917694/3001761.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do an interactive rebase, per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_squashing) and [this blog post](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history#squash-commits-together).

1. Start an interactive rebase:

   ```
   git rebase -i HEAD~n
   ```

   (where `n` is how far do you want to go back in history)
2. Your default editor will open. At the top, a list of your latest `n` commits will be displayed, in reverse order. Eg:

   ```
   pick a5f4a0d commit-1
   pick 19aab46 commit-2
   pick 1733ea4 commit-3
   pick 827a099 commit-4
   pick 10c3f38 commit-5
   pick d32d526 commit-6
   ```
3. Specify `squash` (or the shortcut `s`) for all commits you want to squash. E.g.:

   ```
   pick a5f4a0d commit-1
   pick 19aab46 commit-2
   squash 1733ea4 commit-3
   squash 827a099 commit-4
   pick 10c3f38 commit-5
   pick d32d526 commit-6
   ```

   Git applies both that change and the change directly before it and makes you merge the commit messages together.
4. Save and exit.
5. Git will apply all changes and will open again your editor to merge the three commit messages. You can modify your commit messages or leave it as it is (if so, the commit messages of all commits will be concatenated).
6. You're done! The commits you selected will all be squashed with the previous one.

Comment: Just to confirm. In this case example you put, commits 2, 3, 4 will be squashed into a single commit, let's call it commit `2*`. My new history will look contain the commits `1, 2*, 5, 6`. In addition, `1` will preserve its old SHA-1, but `2*, 5, 6` will all get new SHA-1 hashes. Am I correct?

Comment: @becko correct -- commit 2* gets a new hash because the contents of the commit are now different; commits 5 and 6 get a new hash because their parent commit IDs have changed. For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32854964/11298742

Comment: And then how do I push this, if the commits I have just squashed were already pushed to remote? After editing the commit message, I see "Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged, and have 4 and 10 different commits each, respectively. (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Comment: @pretzlstyle an interactive rebase changes git commit history. If you have already pushed and you're working with other developers, you should avoid modifying git commit history as it can have important implications. If you understand those implications, --force would be an option (Warning: "Do not use the --force flag unless you’re absolutely sure you know what you’re doing")

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bash `function` to automatically mark commit `n2` and all commits between `n1` and `n2` as `fixup`. This way you don't have to manually mark every commit with `fixup`. It supports a `DRY_RUN` argument that prints the contents of the "interactive rebase file", so you can play around with the values of `START` and `END`. `START` and `END` indicate the index of the commits:
e.g.: If this is the file you want

```
pick a5f4a0d commit-1
pick 19aab46 commit-2
fixup 1733ea4 commit-3
fixup 827a099 commit-4
pick 10c3f38 commit-5
pick d32d526 commit-6
```

`START=3` and `END=4`.

The code:

```
function squash() {
# example use:
# DRY_RUN=1 START=2 END=4 squash HEAD~4
# START=2 END=4 squash HEAD~4
  mkdir -p /tmp/squash
  if [ -n "${DRY_RUN}" ] && [ "${DRY_RUN}" -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo "
sed  -i \"\"  "${START},${END}s/^[^[:space:]]*/fixup/" \$1
echo 
echo ***START***
echo \"\"
cat \$1
echo \"\"
echo ***END***
echo The error message \"error: there was a problem with the editor squash\" is normal when running DRY_RUN=1
exit 1 # force exit to not actually rebase
    " > /tmp/squash/squash
  else
    echo "
sed  -i \"\"  "${START},${END}s/^[^[:space:]]*/fixup/" \$1
    " > /tmp/squash/squash
  fi
  chmod +x /tmp/squash/squash
  OLDPATH=${PATH}
  export PATH="/tmp/squash:${PATH}"
  GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=squash git rebase -i "$@"
  export PATH=${OLDPATH}
}
```

Comment: I'm on a mac, if anyone can confirm the `sed` is working on Linux that would be nice.