# Git merge different commits into one group by user

Tags: git

We are 2 developers working on the same branch. Let's say, dev1 working on login and dev2 working on registration.

Here are the commits:

- dev1 commit 1
- dev1 commit 2
- dev2 commit 1
- dev2 commit 2
- dev1 commit 3
- dev2 commit 3

---

I would like to know if there's a possibility to squash commits and merge them by the user

final commits list:

- dev1 login (combining dev1's commit 1, 2, 3)
- dev2 registration (combining dev2's commit 1, 2, 3)

Comment: This is a pair of rebases, however you want to do them. `git rebase -i oldest~..` and pick squash squash the two series, or `git reset oldest~; git cherry-pick -n d11 d12 d13; git commit; git cherry-piick -n d21 d22 d23; git commit`.

Comment: This answer might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262851/12974735

Comment: @Sercan That thread will squash them to previous commit rather than rearranging them with a new commit.

Answer (score 0):

#### *How to rearrange and squash commits*

> OP: I would like to know if there's a possibility to squash commits and merge them by the user

In order to achieve what you are asking for, the easiest approach I'd say would be to do an ***interactive rebase***, e.g.

```
$ git rebase master feature-1 --interactive
```

See the illustration below for a detailed explanation.

[image: Illustration of an interactive rebase]

##### Step by step

- (1) Select which two branches to involve in the rebase (don't forget the `--intertactive` flag as it will allow you to rearrange your commits)
- (2.1) Re-order your commits in the desired order (note that the commits are displayed in reversed order)
- (2.1) Edit the action infront of the commits to squash from `pick` to `squash` or `fixup` (depending on if you'd like to edit the commit message or not)
- (3) Save and close the file and watch Git work its magic

##### Important

As `rebase` rewrites your history, make sure to take a backup of your branch first. That way you're also able to easily compare the before and after state of the two branches.

Further more, re-arranging commits assumes that the intertwined developers have been working on the same files as this could potentially cause conflicts while rebasing.